# What's the difference between these two styles of writing jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When should I do this:

```
$.test = {
  foo: function() {
    this.bar();
  },
  bar: function() {
  }
}

$.test.foo();
```

And when should I do this?

```
$.testFoo = function() {
  $.testBar();
}
$.testBar = function() {
}

$.testFoo();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following defines an [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) with two methods

```
$.test = {
  foo: function() {
    this.bar();
  },
  bar: function() {
  }
}

$.test.foo();
```

This just defines two functions

```
$.testFoo = function() {
  $.testBar();
}
$.testBar = function() {
}

$.testFoo();
```

If you want to associate the two functions with each other then use an object. If the functions do two completely different things then just define separate functions